# Send mail in oracle with UTF-8 encoding in subject

Tags: oracle, email, encoding, utf-8

I need to send an email from Oracle, with special characters in a subject, like ŠŽČĐĆšžčćđ.

I found some information here:
https://journal.missiondata.com/sending-utf-8-email-with-oracle-d276a05cf94b

My code looks like this:

```
UTL_SMTP.helo (l_mail_conn, l_mailhost);
UTL_SMTP.mail (l_mail_conn, p_sender);
UTL_SMTP.rcpt (l_mail_conn, p_recipient);
UTL_SMTP.open_data (l_mail_conn);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, 'From' || ': ' || p_sender || CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, 'To' || ': ' || p_recipient || CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?' || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.QUOTED_PRINTABLE_ENCODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(p_subject))) || '?=' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, 'MIME-version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable '|| UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(l_mail_conn, UTL_ENCODE.QUOTED_PRINTABLE_ENCODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(p_message)));
UTL_SMTP.close_data (l_mail_conn);
UTL_SMTP.quit (l_mail_conn);
```

If I use uppercase letters (ČŽŠĆ) only, everything works great.
But, if there is at least one lowercase letter on the subject, it gets corrupted.

Instead of

> TEST(ČŽŠ)ščžž

i get

> =?UTF-8?Q?TEST(=C4=8C=C5=BD=C5=A0)=C5=A1=

Oracle DB 12c uses AL32UTF8 character set.

I also tried the following code, which works for a majority of users, but there are some mail servers/mail clients which do not detect subject encoding correctly.

```
UTL_SMTP.helo (l_mail_conn, l_mailhost);
UTL_SMTP.mail (l_mail_conn, p_sender);
UTL_SMTP.rcpt (l_mail_conn, p_recipient);
UTL_SMTP.open_data (l_mail_conn);

UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, 'From' || ': ' || p_sender || CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, 'To' || ': ' || p_recipient || CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(l_mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Subject' || ': ' || p_subject ));
UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(l_mail_conn,utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_message));
UTL_SMTP.close_data (l_mail_conn);
UTL_SMTP.quit (l_mail_conn);
```

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

I tried to send an email with the same subject from Outlook and from Oracle. I used BASE64 encoding. Both internet headers in Outlook are the same, 
but only for subject "subject like ŠŽČĐĆšžčćđ"

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?c3ViamVjdCBsaWtlIMWgxb3EjMSQxIbFocW+xI3Eh8SR?=
```

When I change subject to "subject like ŠŽČĐĆšžčćđ: (test Ščž)" things get wrong:

Sent from Outlook:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?
c3ViamVjdCBsaWtlIMWgxb3EjMSQxIbFocW+xI3Eh8SROiAodGVzdCDFoMSN?=
 =?utf-8?B?xb4p?=
```

Sent from Oracle:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?
c3ViamVjdCBsaWtlIMWgxb3EjMSQxIbFocW+xI3Eh8SROiAodGVzdCDFoMSNxb4p
```

It seems there are some new line/carriage return characters, which cause troubles. Outlook puts =?utf-8?B? in front of every line, Oracle doesn't...

I tested this with SQL

```
select 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('subject like ŠŽČĐĆšžčćđ: (test Ščž)'))) || '?=' 
from dual
```

returns

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?c3ViamVjdCBsaWtlIMWgxb3EjMSQxIbFocW+xI3Eh8SROiAodGVzdCDFoMSNxb4p
?=
```

I fixed it with replace:

```
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' ||
                            replace(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('subject like ŠŽČĐĆšžčćđ: (test Ščž)'))),CHR(13) || CHR(10),'?=' || CHR(13) || CHR(10)||' =?utf-8?B?')
                            || '?=' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
```

It works now... but I was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Yes, BASE64 encoding permits NEWLINE, they are ignored for decoding. it is quite common to put NEWLINE each 64 characters, some variants even force it, see [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table). I think your solution is the most useful.

Comment: Thank you for yout hints, you helped me a lot :D

Comment: See my update and try it.

Comment: I tried, It's not working :/

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Subject:

```
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_raw_DATA(c, UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('Subject: '||REPLACE(utl_encode.MIMEHEADER_ENCODE(Subj, 'utf8'),CHR(13) || CHR(10),'') || utl_tcp.CRLF));
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this one is working:

```
Subject := '=?utf-8?B?'
    || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('subject like ŠŽČĐĆšžčćđ')))
    || '?='

UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: '||Subject||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
...
UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(l_mail_conn,utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_message));
```

Try an additional `UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);` before `UTL_SMTP.close_data`

You have some `CRLF` instead of `UTL_TCP.CRLF` - is this the same? Better use always `UTL_TCP.CRLF`.

Then you have a extra (or missing) double-quote in `UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);`

Review your code carefully.

**Update**

Maybe try

```
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?'||UTL_ENCODE.TEXT_ENCODE(Subject, NULL, UTL_ENCODE.QUOTED_PRINTABLE)||'?=' ||UTL_TCP.CRLF );
```

`TEXT_ENCODE` inserts a NEWLINE each 76 characters, however according [Base64: MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME) they should be ignored.

Comment: Interesting. I tested your code, and it works...but just in your case. When I changed subject to: 'TESTING SUBJECT MAIL: ŠČŽ žšč subject like ŠŽČĐĆšžčćđ', it fails once again.

Comment: What is your NLS_LANG value?

Comment: NLS_LANG = SLOVENIAN_SLOVENIA.EE8MSWIN1250, NLS_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8...could that be the problem?

Comment: I am using SQL Developer. I fixed the code (added double-quote and added extra CRLF), but there is no difference.

Comment: Send a mail using MS Outlook. On received mail go to menu File -> Properties and have a look at Internet Headers. Compare such text carefully with Internet Headers from mail sent by PL/SQL (with wrong display of Subject). Perhaps you will find the difference.

Comment: Check my update. New lines can appear in encoded text, thats the issue probably.