# PL/SQL - Send cyrillic characters using utl_smtp

Tags: plsql, utf-8

In my case I store and retrieve Cyrillic characters into / from Oracle 11g db using NVARCHAR2 columns (see below a simple case)

```
create table cyrillic (texte varchar2(1000), ntexte nvarchar2(1000));
insert into cyrillic (texte, ntexte) values ('Hello World',N'Привет мир');
commit;
select * from cyrillic;
```

My aim now is to use the NVARCHAR2 column to prepare and send an email using UTL_SMTP.

I found several posts related to similar things but none is working (ie: [Send mail in oracle with UTF-8 encoding in subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261876/send-mail-in-oracle-with-utf-8-encoding-in-subject))

I always have a conversion issue in received email.
Is someone had the same need and found a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several days of work and plenty of google search, I found the solution that works in my case.
Here the code:

```
create or replace procedure pr_send_mail_by_rawdata(p_subject nvarchar2, p_body nvarchar2) as
   lv_server  varchar2(255) := 'localhost';
   lv_rcpt    varchar2(255) := 'you@gmail.com';
   lv_from    varchar2(255) := 'me <me@gmail.com>';
   lv_subject varchar2(4000):= 'cyrillic';

   lv_conn    utl_smtp.connection;
begin
   lv_conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(lv_server);
   UTL_SMTP.helo (lv_conn, lv_server);
   UTL_SMTP.mail (lv_conn, lv_from);
   UTL_SMTP.rcpt (lv_conn, lv_rcpt);
   UTL_SMTP.open_data (lv_conn);

   UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn, 'From' || ': ' || lv_from || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
   UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lv_conn, 'To' || ': ' || lv_rcpt || UTL_TCP.CRLF);



   lv_subject := '=?UTF8?Q?'||replace(utl_encode.TEXT_ENCODE(p_subject,'UTF8'),'='||chr(13) || chr(10)) || '?=';
   UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(lv_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Subject' || ': ' || lv_subject||utl_tcp.crlf ));


   utl_smtp.write_data(lv_conn, 'MIME-version: 1.0' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
   utl_smtp.write_data(lv_conn, 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=KOI8-R;'||utl_tcp.CRLF);
   utl_smtp.write_data(lv_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: QUOTED-PRINTABLE'||utl_tcp.CRLF);
   utl_smtp.write_data(lv_conn, utl_encode.TEXT_ENCODE(p_body,'CL8KOI8R'));     
   utl_smtp.write_data(lv_conn, utl_tcp.crlf);      
   utl_smtp.close_data(lv_conn);
   utl_smtp.quit(lv_conn);
end;
```

Two things have been managed differently:

1. The subject:
   Text is converted in utf8.
2. The body:
   Text is converted in KOI8-R (charset : CL8KOI8R)